# Pass information between RecyclerView.Adapter and RecyclerView.ItemAnimator

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Let's suppose we have an Adapter with a date field. When the date changes, the Adapter recalculates the items to display and the ItemAnimator the kind of animation to perform , that is left-to-right or right-to-left whether the new date is before or after the current date.
How do we pass such information to the ItemAnimator to the Adapter?

Consider that:

- ItemAnimator has no direct access to the Adapter.
- ItemAnimator recordPreLayoutInformation accept RecyclerView.State but the State is not accessibile outside of RecyclerView (there's no `getState()` in RecyclerView) and its callbacks, none are available to Adapter, only to ItemDecoration and ItemAnimator.
- The payloads parameter in recordPreLayoutInformation is collected via `Adapter.notifyItemChanged()` only not by `notifyItemInserted()` or `notifyItemRemoved()`.

Discarded options:

- Subclass RecyclerView to implement a `getState()` parameter and obtain a reference to it in `Adapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView()`.
- Pass the Adapter as a parameter to the ItemAnimator.
- Add a shared object between Adapter and ItemAnimator.
- Duplicate date state in both the Adapter and the ItemAnimator.

TL;DR: am I missing the proper way to pass information between Adapter and ItemAnimator?

Comment: So you want to call a animation once a item is changed or removed?

Comment: The issue is that the animations are chosen by the ItemAnimator depending on the Adapter state, but there's no way to access that state from the ItemAnimator.

Comment: cannot you keep the final position (left or right) in your custom `ViewHolder`?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but animations are not or shouldn't be VH's business. Also, I cannot exclude that I need to use the data later, when the VH has been already recycled. I could use the Holder as a temp container just to pass the information, but I'd like a cleaner solution.   
Ideally, ItemAnimator.onRecordPreLayoutInformation seems to be the right place to collect information about that single, specific layout operation, except the Adapter is left out in the cold.

Comment: so extend `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemHolderInfo` and return it from `recordPreLayoutInformation` method, this custom `ItemHolderInfo` will keep your left / right animation direction